# trading view trendline getting cleared one by one

Tags: pine-script

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am using the below code to plot a triangle based on fib levels, the lines will be connecting the fib levels of first 5min candle to end of the day fib levels, i am able to plot but it is getting cleared one by one , please see the image

```
study(title="BreakOut", overlay=true)

up15on = input(true, title="5 Minute Opening Range High")
down15on = input(true, title="5 Minute Opening Range Low")

is_newbar(res) => change(time(res)) != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have reached the maximum number of drawings. From [Pine Script v4 User Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#total-number-of-drawings):

> Drawing objects consume server resources, which is why there is a
>   limit to the total number of drawings per study or strategy. When too
>   many drawings are created, old ones are automatically deleted by the
>   Pine runtime, in a process referred to as *garbage collection*.

Comment: how to override this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to override the limit. Do you really need that many drawings? Consider removing unused lines with `line.delete`.